# React extends for function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component, react-class-based-component

I have a class component that extends another class component:

```
export default class MyLittleComponent extends TheBigBoy
```

Now I need to refactor `MyLittleComponent` to functional component so it works with hooks etc. But then I lose everything inherited from `TheBigBoy`.

Is there a way to write function component AND to keep the dependency/extension of `TheBigBoy`?

`TheBigBoy` is used all over the app so I can't remove it just yet.

I can possibly make a function copy of `TheBigBoy` and then somehow attach it to `MyLittleComponent` but what would be the best way as there's no "extends" for function components as far as I know? A hook of some sort? I want to avoid HOC as that's one of the things I'm running away from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, React team recommends [composition over inheritance](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html).

What you can do though, is to use a two-pronged approach:

1. Move the logic and state management from `TheBigBoy` to a custom hook. Then your `MyLittleComponent` can use that hook.
2. Turn `TheBigBoy` into a component that takes children. You can then pass your `MyLittleComponent` into `TheBigBoy`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).